# Is there a way to lock the D7100's mirror up while burst shooting?

Tags: nikon, burst-mode, nikon-d7100, mirror-lockup

I have a Nikon D7100. I've tried to capture water droplets in burst mode. But the mirror speed limits my shooting and makes a discontinuous series of images, even with a 1/2000 shutter speed!

Is there any way to lock the mirror up during burst shooting? 
I mean to set everything before shooting (like focus, exposure, ... as I should do for this type of photography), then lock the mirror up and shoot.

Is this feature supported by the D7100?

Comment: A friend of mine use a flash with a homemade automatic trigger to shoot water droplet with the camera in bulb mode (and make stunning images). You should probably read about such techniques (yes, your d7100 has the bulb mode).

Answer (score 4):

1/2000 is the time the shutter is open. What you are looking for is frame rate, frames per second (fps), and the two are not directly related.

The D7100 maxes out at 5-7 fps. The mirror lockup seems to be for only one picture at a time (p. 61 in the [user's guide](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/Wt74B00WmPdp01GF7sU080xUqy56/D7100_(En)03.pdf)), and won't increase the frame rate.

You can get a higher frame rate with video: Your camera supports up to 60 fps in video mode, so you could grab a (lower resolution) frame from the video.

If you want more than 60 fps, you'll need something other than the D7100.